# Tizen Web app iframe is in fullscreen instead of in a table

Tags: html, iframe, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm currently coding a small web app for a tizen tv. It mainly consists of a table with 2x2 cells. every cell contains an Iframe to another website.

But when i ran it on my TV i noticed that instead of four websites, only one website was shown in fullscreen. I set the table's size to 100% height and width.
Thank you in advance

I tried using 100vh/vw for the size instead of percentages

Comment: Would you add some codes for tests?

Comment: What TV are you running this on? The CSS support on older Tizen displays are really bad and could be the CSS you are using is not supported. 100vh etc will only work on Tizen 6.5+. Secondly do the iframes you are embedding have videos in them? If so this could be the issue as again depending on platform you are running on only 2-3 html videos will be supported.